# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax at line 7

Tags: mysql, sql

```
enter code here
    DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Update_Status`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `Update_Status` AFTER INSERT ON `occurance_time`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `F_Seen` FROM `Total_Hours` WHERE (`SSN`=new.`SSN` and `Day_Date`=new.`Day_Date`))
THEN
INSERT INTO `total_time` (`SSN`,`Name`,`Day_Date`,`F_Seen`) VALUES(new.`SSN`,new.`Name`,new.`Day_Date`,new.`Cap_time`);
ELSE
UPDATE `total_time` SET(`L_Seen`=new.`Cap_time`) WHERE (`SSN`=new.`SSN` and `Day_Date`=new.`Day_Date`);
END$$
```

---

I have Created this After insert trigger On Occurrence _time I want to store first time of occurrence of a day and last time of occurrence of Day in Total_time table but getting this Error
"1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(`L_Seen`=new.`Cap_time`) WHERE (`SSN`=new.`SSN` and `Day_Date`=new.`Day_Date...' at line 7"  ***

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SET(L_Seen=new.Cap_time)` Please use `SET L_Seen=new.Cap_time`. You missed `end if` also. Below code is working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update_Status` AFTER INSERT ON `occurance_time`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `F_Seen` FROM `Total_Hours` WHERE `SSN`=new.`SSN` and `Day_Date`=new.`Day_Date`)
THEN
INSERT INTO `total_time` (`SSN`,`Name`,`Day_Date`,`F_Seen`) VALUES(new.`SSN`,new.`Name`,new.`Day_Date`,new.`Cap_time`);
ELSE
UPDATE `total_time` SET `L_Seen`=new.`Cap_time`  WHERE `SSN`=new.`SSN` and `Day_Date`=new.`Day_Date`;
end if;
end
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table occurance_time(SSN varchar(50),Name varchar(50),Day_Date date,Cap_time time);

 CREATE TRIGGER Update_Status AFTER INSERT ON occurance_time 
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT F_Seen FROM total_time WHERE SSN=new.SSN and Day_Date=new.Day_Date) 
 THEN
 INSERT INTO total_time (SSN,Name,Day_Date,F_Seen) VALUES(new.SSN,new.Name,new.Day_Date,new.Cap_time); 
 ELSE
 UPDATE total_time SET L_Seen=new.Cap_time WHERE SSN=new.SSN and Day_Date=new.Day_Date; 
 end if; 
 end
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=903ac619075095684e97e933faf99b87)*

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: I have revised my answer. It's working now.

Comment: I don't know why but it is still giving syntax error on line 6

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER Update_Status
AFTER INSERT ON occurance_time
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT F_Seen FROM total_time WHERE SSN=new.SSN and Day_Date=new.Day_Date) 
THEN 
INSERT INTO total_time (SSN,Name,Day_Date,F_Seen) VALUES(new.SSN,new.Name,new.Day_Date,new.Cap_time);
ELSE 
UPDATE total_time SET L_Seen=new.Cap_time WHERE SSN=new.SSN and Day_Date=new.Day_Date;
end if; 
end

Comment: There should not be any syntax error in your above code. I have added db-fiddle link. Is there any part of query missing in above example?

Comment: yes its right and total_time table have attributes (SSN , Name ,Day_Date, F_Seen,L_Seen,houres.) me goal is to save First Occurrence in FSeen and Update L_Seen With Each Occurrence.